# Is there a Perl subroutine for exist and defined?

Tags: perl, operators, subroutine

I use exists and defined in if statements all the time

```
if (exists($a->{b}) and defined($a->{b})
```

is there a subroutine that does both of these at the same time?

**UPDATE:**
Seems I didn't give very good example code. For a better question and matching answer check out [checking-for-existence-of-hash-key-creates-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789333/checking-for-existence-of-hash-key-creates-key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defined(...)` can only be true when `exists(...)` is true, so the answer to your question is that the subroutine is called `defined`.

Comment: That's not right. At worst you inadvertently promote `$a` to a hash reference when you use the `->` operator on it.

Comment: It should be noted that my initial assumption was wrong (defined does not create a key).

Comment: nit: `defined` is an operator, not a sub.

Answer (score 6):

That's the same thing as

```
if (defined($a->{b}))
```

---

Regarding the reply in the comments, `defined` does not instantiate the keys.

```
>perl -E"if (exists($a->{b}) and defined($a->{b})) { }  say 0+keys(%$a);"
0

>perl -E"if (defined($a->{b})) { }  say 0+keys(%$a);"
0
```

`->`, on the other hand, autovivifies as normal.

```
>perl -E"if (defined($a->{b})) { }  say $a || 0;"
HASH(0x3fbd8c)
```

But that's the case for `exists` too.

```
>perl -E"if (exists($a->{b}) and defined($a->{b})) { }  say $a || 0;"
HASH(0x81bd7c)
```

If you're trying to avoid autovivification, you'd use

```
>perl -E"if ($a && defined($a->{b})) { }  say $a || 0;"
0
```

or

```
>perl -E"no autovivification; if (defined($a->{b})) { }  say $a || 0;"
0
```

Comment: Nope, when using defined on a hash you inadvertently create the key.

Comment: "No, it doesn't" is the answer of a 5yo. Don't contradict someone without backing it up, or at least verifying your claim. My code will never create a key. It can create a hash ref in `$a`, but so can your original code. (It's `->` that creates the hash ref, and that's the first thing executed in both your code and my code.)

Comment: @EricFossum You may be thinking of autovivification, which occurs if you use `defined` on a two-dimensional structure, such as `defined $foo->{bar}{baz}`, which creates the sublevel `$foo->{bar}` but not baz.

Comment: @TLP, I know, You seem to have misunderstood me. I was saying that autovifivication is not a "problem" introduced in my code. It existed in the original. (PS - my name is Eric too)

Comment: @ikegami Ah yes, I see what you mean.. I was thinking of the keys, but you're right, the hash ref is also created.

Comment: Well seems like you would be right if you would have explained some more. I must have been doing something else when I used defined before. However, defined and exists ARE different and you seem to think they are the same.

Comment: @Eric Fossum, Of course `exists` and `defined` are different. What isn't different is `exists && defined` and `defined`.

Comment: @ikegami - I agree 'exists && defined and defined', but I must be doing this autovivication somewhere. I don't know what it is though, I think I'll go look it up now.

Comment: @Eric Fossum, autovivification is the creation of hash or array when dereferencing an undefined scalar. e.g. `$h->{k}` is effectively short for `( $h //= {} )->{k}` because of autovivification. It has nothing to do with `defined` or `exists`. I showed two ways around it in my previously updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

- **exists()** checks if the key exists (even if undef value)
- **defined()** checks if there is a value defined

if you only want to check if the key exists (even if undef) then just use **exists()**

here is a related questions that explains it quite nicely : [What's the difference between exists and defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534573/whats-the-difference-between-exists-and-defined)